# Joining parent with one example of child

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a parent table, call it `parents`.  Each parent has some number of children in a second table, called `children`.  A typical left join would be something like this:

```
select * 
from parents p 
left join children c
on p.id = c.parent_id
```

But this returns every child row and repeats all the parent information.  What I want instead (for this application) is the first child for each parent, so that the resultset has the same number of rows as the parent table.

```
Parent1  Child_of_parent1_1
Parent2  Child_of_parent2_1
Parent3  Child_of_parent3_1
```

I've tried to put distinct in strange places but can't seem to figure this one out.

Comment: add GROUP BY parent_id at the end of your query

Comment: Hmm, this definitely works in mySql but I'm not sure it works cross-platform.  As this is a mySql environment I don't think that I should care :D.  Thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT A.* FROM
(
   SELECT p.*, c.child_id, some_field_of_children
   FROM  parents p 
   LEFT JOIN children c ON p.id = c.parent_id
) A
WHERE A.child_id = ( SELECT MIN(B.child_id) FROM children B WHERE B.parent_id = A.parent_id)
```

I assume that children table has 'child_id' as its PK that we can use to get the first child.

You can replace child_id by another column like 'timestamp' OR 'child_position', ...

Comment: nice solution, I think it can be done without the first subquery.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: The first subquery (A) is needed. You can test.

Answer (score 0):

Freehand SQL:
Select *
from Parent p
cross join Child c 
where c.Id = (select max(c2.id) from Child c2 where c2.ParentId = p.Id)

Something like that will get 1 child with the current Parent and join the two.
If you want it return stuff if there are no children, ann:

or not exists(select max(c3.id) from Child c3 where c3.ParentId = p.Id)

Cheers -

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
p.parent_id, 
p.name as parent_name, 
c.name as child_name 
from parent p
join(
   select * from child where child_id in(
      select child_id from child
      group by parent_id)) c
on p.parent_id = c.parent_id
```

**SQL Fiddle:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/03fdc/14